# Bizarre Wordpress/CSS issue

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My page displays fine in Chrome but in Safari and Firefox the top is cut off and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Perhaps if someone could take a look and offer some advice?

Page is here->

http://blog.praxispr.ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not displaying correctly for me in Chrome either.

Cut the line: `top: -28px` under the `body` selector in your stylesheet. I'm not sure why it is there.

Comment: Hmmm well when I remove that line I get the opposite problem in Chrome only- the nav now has a space above it at the top, but it's fine in Safari and Firefox. Can you see that too?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I've inspected your html again, and found nothing that could cause that behavior. But now that I think of it, I know one of my friend's pc does the same thing in chrome to many websites for no reason at all. I didn't give it much thought at the time but what I suspect now is that it's some kind of plugin that might be installed. Don't you see this behavior in other sites as well? If so, try reinstalling chrome - who knows, that might do it.

Comment: Huh. Strange. Well as long as it's not in the code I'm happy!